# FPS much lower on iPad than iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, sprite-kit, ios-simulator

I know that the iOS simulator won't offer nearly as much performance as the device itself. That being said my FPS for iPad simulations are approximately half or a quarter of iPhone simulations. My device itself is near 60 FPS, but why is the iPad slower than iPhone. I have pretty close to the same amount of nodes on both simulations due to scaling.

I'm no expert on rendering but will that extra resolution really make the FPS suffer that much? Or are there other common problems to look out for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the larger devices will have poorer graphics performance in the simulator due to their, well, larger size ;)

All rendering in the iOS Simulator is done in software.

If you have graphics intensive apps, you might want to have a "low quality" setting for use in the simulator for rapid deployment testing and then verify performance and render quality on a real device.

Comment: I thought only OpenGL rendering was software emulated on the simulator, not all rendering.

Comment: Your terminology is off there.  OpenGLES isn't software emulated, it's implemented in software as opposed to hardware.  Also, Quartz2D is implemented in software.  There's also no Metal support.